# Clean return data in Python - xlswriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I would like some help with the python method below. As you can see below the function returns some data in a list.

```
def EIS(self):
    '''This function runs EIS experiment'''

    #some code here

    frequencies=[100000.0,79432.8,63095.7,50118.7,39810.7,31622.8,25118.9]
    Data = []
    for freq in (frequencies) :
        #print(freq)
        self.sendcommand("GS_SetBestCurrentRange", timeout=0.1)
        self.sendcommand("GS_FRASetModulationFrequency %.5f" %freq, timeout=0.1)
        self.sendcommand("GS_FRAGetMeasurementMinDurationMS", timeout=0.1)
        self.sendcommand("GS_FRAMakeMeasurement 1", timeout=0.1)
        self.sendcommand("GS_GetCurrentRange")
        VoltageSamples = self.sendcommand("PS_FRAGetVoltageSample", timeout=0.1)
        #CurrentSample = self.sendcommand("PS_FRAGetCurrentSample", timeout=0.1).split(" ")
        Data.append(VoltageSamples,)
        print (Data)
    return Data
```

My problem is that the return data i m having do not have the right format.Below you can see what it returns:

```
['GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.00699254 -213.701 0\r']
['GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.00699254 -213.701 0\r', 'GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0128992 -187.322 0\r']
```

I want to clear the Data so it can only return the floating numbers (0.00699254 -213.701 etc...) and I would like lets say numbers 0.00699254 and 0.0128992 to be in one column and -213.701 and -187.322 to be in another column. I use the xlswriter library and I'm calling that function:

```
Data= TEST.EIS()
worksheet4.write_column('A1',Data)
```

but it outputs all the data in A1 column like this

```
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.00699254 -213.701 0"
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0128992 -187.322 0"
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0113329 -67.7349 0"
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0110053 -63.2269 0"
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0149435 -51.8437 0"
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0131203 -38.0366 0"
"GS_FRAGetVoltageSample 0.0120906 -35.6771 0"
```

Any help of how I can clean the data and make them to go in different columns?

Comment: You do know that the `print(Data)` line in your code prints once per iteration and that the `return Data` is returning just the last line of your output.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want. We can see what you actually get, but I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: the return data is not returning just the last line as you can see from the return i gave you. It appends in each iteration the last data to the list. This is working. The problem is how to clean the data to be in asuitable format for xlswiter as i mention above. Ty

Comment: The `Data` variable you create is a list: `[]`. Then you append stuff to it and return it at the end. What you have printed is two lists: `[...] [...]`. What I am expecting is that Data contains `[stuff, more stuff]`

Comment: It is one list the second line of the return data has one return data and then appends the second and goes on till the for loop finishes. It has the format you said [1,2] but in the line before is the list [1] with the first data. The list fills up in each iteration

Comment: I've told you that: You `print(Data)` once per iteration. btw, how long is `frequencies`? It looks like a list of 7 items, so I would expect that Data eventually holds 7 items.

Comment: You should do: `Data= TEST.EIS()   print(Data)` and not print inside `EIS`

Comment: yes is 7 items. i didn't put it all to save some space. This is not the question. The question is how to clean the data so i have only the numbers

Comment: You need to tell us what the output should look like.

Comment: as you can see in the xlswriter there are 7 results.

Comment: 0.00699254 -213.701

Comment: Ok, you need to show us what the 7 results *should* look like.

Comment: 0.0128992 -187.322 like that only the numbers. The 0.0128992 should go on the A1 column and the -187.322 should go on the A2 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean up `VoltageSamples`:

```
def EIS(self):
    ...
    Data = []
    for freq in frequencies:
        ...
        ...
        VoltageSamples = self.sendcommand . . . 
        samples = VoltageSamples.split()
        Data.append( (samples[1], samples[2]) )
    return Data
```

Then you need to insert two different lists, one into A1, and another into A2:

```
Data = TEST.EIS()
print(Data)
list1, list2 = zip(*Data)

worksheet4.write_column('A1', list1)
worksheet4.write_column('B1', list2)
```

**Update:**

I have used this test code to verify my suggestions above:

```
frequencies=[31622.8, 25118.9]
Data = []
for freq in frequencies:
    VoltageSamples = ' '.join(('foo', str(freq), 'bar', 'zoo'))
    samples = VoltageSamples.split()
    Data.append( (samples[1], samples[2]) )

print(Data)
list1, list2 = zip(*Data)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

The output I get is:

```
[('31622.8', 'bar'), ('25118.9', 'bar')]
('31622.8', '25118.9')
('bar', 'bar')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that returns inalid syntax at print Data. any idea y?

Comment: found it a bracket was missing

Comment: list1, list2 = zip(*Data)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) Almost there. whats the error now?

Comment: Check my update where I only append two samples onto Data.

Comment: I checked. I m afraid that puts all the numbers in one column A1 only, A2 is empty

Comment: See my update where I show the output from some test code. Both lists have something in them. `Data` has a list of tuples. The two lists each get a column from `Data`.

Comment: if on the xlswiter you replace write_column with write_row it works for me. it puts them in different rows than different columns but is good enough i think i will still be able to make a graph. I am going to try the other way now and let you know. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ok, I've just checked with `Excel` and the letters are the columns, so you should write to `A1` then`B1`. Answer updated.

Comment: My friend you are a winner. You made my weekend. Thank you very much. It works perfectly!!!

Comment: Well, we've both worked hard on this problem. Any up votes would be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to give you but it doesnt let me as my level is still pretty low. But again ty very much and have a great weekend.